# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated - how to find which exact insert statement?

Tags: c#, edmx

I know few similar questions like this has been asked before in SO. But my question is little different.
I have a code block similar to this -

```
     using (DBWebEntities db = new DBWebEntities())
            {
                if (StatusDict != null && StatusDict.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, job_status> kvp in JobStatusDict)
                    { db.AddToEmp_status(kvp.Value); }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

As you can see, I am running the db.saveChanges() together for all the insert queries at the end.
I am getting the exception for some of the entities.
How do I figure out from the exception its happening exactly for which Entity value?

As I checked the innerexception I could only find the stack trace not the entity which caused this.

I am using .NET 4.

Comment: See the inner exception

Comment: Umm... the exception also includes a list with the failed entity entries, if i am not mistaken... (It is an DbUpdateException, right?)

Comment: checked the inner exception already. Its showing  the stacktrace but not the entity which caused it. I am using .NET 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I finally found it out.
Hover over 'ex'-> expand System.Data.UpdateException -> Expand 'State Entries' - here you can see a the objects causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
```

Hover over ex.  Interrogate entityvalidationerrors, dbentityvalidationresult, Entry, Entity :  to see the value that you are trying to get into the db and the field name.

Interrogate entityvalidationerrors, dbentityvalidationresult, Entry, Entity --to see the table you need

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check if that works and let you know.